# Vectorising a nested loop

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

```
for k=1:n
    for m=1:n_
        K_anv(k,m,:)=exp(-(x(k,:)-z(m,:)).^2./(2*l'.^2))-A(k,:).*A_(m,:)./B;
    end
end
```

`K_anv` is 3D matrix representing a kernel where `k` is the number of data and `m` is the number of estimation points. `x` and `z` are `n x D` and `n_ x D` matrices (`l` is `D x 1` vector).

Can I obliterate the loop in this case?

Comment: What are `A` and `B`?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample inputs to make this runnable? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: A is nXD and A_ is n_XD matrices. B is 1XD vector

Comment: Just a thought: I removed the underscore after `n_` in the second `for`, as I thought it a typo. Naming your variables this way is rather confusing to anyone but yourself at this moment, and probably will be confusing to you as well when you look at this code in 6 months.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your comment! I may use another variable instead of n_.

Comment: If the answer you received helped you out, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows on the answer. This will signal the community you no longer need help and that this answer helped you solve your question. Additionally this will get both you and @Divakar a bit of reputation. There is no obligation to accept any answer however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Piecemeal vectorization* using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Vectorize "-(x(k,:)-z(m,:)).^2" & thus "exp(-(x(k,:)-z(m,:)).^2./(2*l'.^2))"
xz = -bsxfun(@minus,permute(x,[1 3 2]),permute(z,[3 1 2])).^2 %//'
parte1 = exp(bsxfun(@rdivide,xz,permute(2*l'.^2,[1 3 2])))    %//'

%// Vectorize "A(k,:).*A_(m,:)" & thus "A(k,:).*A_(m,:)./B"
AA_ = bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(A_,[3 1 2]))
parte2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,AA_,permute(B,[1 3 2]))

%// Finally subtract parte2 from parte1 to get K_anv equivalent
K_anv_out = parte1 - parte2;
```

Comment: @JaeminSon If this answer worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it. Read more about accepting answers here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work